# Unusual observation in photoelectric effect simulation

Tags: photoelectric-effect

I was studying a photoelectric simulation (http://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulation/photoelectric) and I observed a really unusual thing. When I held intensity and potential at a constant value and then varied the frequency I observed that there was peak in photocurrent. That is, it first increased when moving towards ultraviolet and then decreased. Please try it yourself and explain.

Comment: A couple of notes: any one who tries to answer this will be *guessing* because you haven't told us *anything*; and secondly if you haven't simply screwed up somehow, you may be seeing some analogous to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franck%E2%80%93Hertz_experiment

Comment: sir i am just a high school student .i just ran the simulation that i posted in my question and then observed this.http://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulation/photoelectric

Comment: Ah...heck. You said you're running a program and I just didn't read. Please accept my apologies, but I won't even guess. Ask the programmer or the support team. Simulations are always at risk of being buggy.

Comment: This is a well-formed question. I can verify the observation in the PhET simulation.

Comment: BMS: sir pls elaborate.this we i should not achieve a peak

Answer (score 1):

You are increasing the energy of each photon, but holding the intensity constant. If you do this, fewer and fewer photons are leaving the lamp, so fewer and fewer are hitting the metal. This is probably the effect you are seeing.

Comment: correct answer. this is mentioned in the teacher's guide that comes with the simulator. we don't see this in textbooks because those examples usually assume an arbitrarily high intensity of light so that the number of photoelectrons emitted is NEVER limited by the number of photons impinging on the metal. the focus tends to be on photon frequency and work function of the metal